# Suppress Cyrus SASL log messages in Apache log file

Tags: apache2, debian, logging, sasl

We are running the stock Apache 2.4 using Debian jessie. We see these sorts of log entries in our syslog:

```
2016-07-31T05:22:12.647897-07:00 www1 apache2: GSSAPI client step 1
```

Some searching suggests that these are generated by the Cyrus SASL libraries with the log level set too high. Is there any way to configure the Cyrus SASL libraries (or Apache) to suppress these messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Cyrus SASL, reported in the [mail thread](https://lists.andrew.cmu.edu/pipermail/cyrus-sasl/2015-January/002785.html) upstream.

It is already [fixed](https://github.com/wingtk/cyrus-sasl/pull/1) in the [upstream fork](https://github.com/wingtk/cyrus-sasl/pull/2) in github, nut it probably didn't made it to the Debian package.

With the above patches, the caller of the cyrus-sasl library (appache) should be able to filter the non-relevant log messages using callback log functions as described in the first mail thread.